# Check if file with "ftp" url exists using java

Tags: java, file, url, ftp

please, could anyone tell me, how can i check if file exists on URL where is only FTP protocol? Im using this code:

```
   public boolean exists(String URLName) throws IOException {
        input = null;
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            input = new URL(URLName).openStream();
            System.out.println("SUCCESS");
            result = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("FAIL");
        } finally {
            if (input != null) {
                input.close();
                input = null;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

It doesnt work when i send there more then one or two, it just sais

```
    sun.net.ftp.FtpProtocolException: Welcome message: 421 Too many connections (2) from this IP

        at sun.net.ftp.FtpClient.openServer(FtpClient.java:490)
        at sun.net.ftp.FtpClient.openServer(FtpClient.java:475)


at sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.connect(FtpURLConnection.java:270)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.getInputStream(FtpURLConnection.java:352)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1010)
    at bibparsing.PDFImage.exists(PDFImage.java:168)
    at bibparsing.PDFImage.main(PDFImage.java:189)
```

It works great when the protocol is HTTP. I mean adresses like:

ftp://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/pub/cmp/articles/chum/Chum-TR-2001-27.pdf
ftp://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/pub/cmp/articles/martinec/Kamberov-ISVC2006.pdf
and something like that

Comment: Make sure only one connection is active at a time, so use a Semaphore with 1 open ticket ,and release tickets when a connection 'does it's purpose' ...

Comment: I guess for checking existence , its better to make request with HTTP and if further , you want to download that file than go for FTP

Comment: please paste the complete exception/stacktrace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that this method isn't **thread safe**; if two threads use this method simultaneously one can overwrite the instance variable named *input*, causing the other thread to not closing the connection it opened (and closing either nothing, or the connection opened by the other thread).

This is easily fixed, by making the *input* variable local:

```
InputStream input=null;
```

**Code style:** within a method, you can return the result as soon as you know it. Beginners often declare the variables first, then execute the logic and return the result at the end of the method. You can save a lot of code and complexity by

- declaring variables *as late as possible* (when you first need them)
- declaring *as few variables as necessary* (readability is always a good reason to add variables, but less variables means less complexity)
- returning *as soon as you know the result* (reducing paths through your code, and thus reducing complexity)

The code can be simply written as:

```
public static boolean exists (String urlName) throws IOException {
    try {
        new URL(urlName).openStream().close();
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```