# ftp connection to determine if file is there

Tags: java, file, url, connection

I am trying to check if the file exist in the FTP. When testing with one user it seems to be fine. But with the scenario of multiple users it seems to throw the below exception :
Exception in thread "main" sun.net.ftp.FtpProtocolException: Welcome message: 421.

Below is the code which we use to check if file is there and we have closed all the connection but still it throws sun.net.ftp.FtpProtocolException:Welcome message: 421.

```
 public boolean getFtpFileExists(String fileUrl)
  {
    URL theURL = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    FtpURLConnection ftpUrlConn = null;
    boolean ftpFileExists = false;

    try
    {
      theURL = new URL(fileUrl);
      ftpUrlConn = (FtpURLConnection)theURL.openConnection();
      inputStream = ftpUrlConn.getInputStream();//calling this method will throw a 'FileNotFoundException' if doesn't exist

      ftpFileExists = true;
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe)
    {
      ftpFileExists = false;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      System.out.println(e.toString());
      ftpFileExists = false;//hmm, not sure really!
    }
    finally
    {
      //close inputStream & connection
      if(inputStream != null)
      {
        try
        {
          inputStream.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {
          System.out.println("Error closing input stream: "+ioe.getMessage());
        }
      }

      try
      {
        ftpUrlConn.close();
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
        System.out.println("Error closing ftpUrlConnection");
      }
    }

    return ftpFileExists;
  }
```

could anyone help me please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if file with "ftp" url exists using java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316468/check-if-file-with-ftp-url-exists-using-java)

Answer (score 0):

Can you recreate the error that you get ?

at any case:

by the error MSG:

> 421: Service not available, closing control connection. This may be a
>   reply to any command if the service knows it must shut down.

It sounds like that maybe there's a configuration needs to be done at the FTPServer rather than a code error.